# process synchronization for MailSlot

Tags: c++, winapi, interprocess, mailslot

I am trying to make interprocess communication between two processes on windows, from an high level of perspective I want to synchronize these two processes, let say there are two processes, process 1 process 2,

Process 1 is an 32 bit application and process 2 is an 64 bit application,
process 1 is running, sometimes it is calling process 2, process 2 runs for short terms and closes it self, process 2 needs to read some data from process 1 when it is opened.

For this scenario I thought MailSlot could be a good candidate, in order to communicate over mail slot process 2 must create a mail slot, then process 1 should send mail to this mail slot, and than process 2 should read mail slot, my question is how can I synchronize these two processes so that when process 2 is opened it creates a mail slot, than it triggers process 1 to send mail and switches to a wait state, than process 1 sends mail to process 2, than process 2 switches to run state and reads mail.

How can I implement such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process1 creates a [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

process1 starts process2.

process1 [wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on event to signal.

process2 creates its mailslot.

process2 [opens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the event object

process2 [signals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the event.

process1 send the data to process2.

process1 [resets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the event.

Or trying to reuse the code you now have, add a mailslot in process1 to get notified from process2 to send parameters to process2's mailslot.

Comment: It worked, Thank you very much. I am a newbie in interprocess communication, I didn't know that I could use events.